# Hive - first table row returned as null even when "skip.header.line.count"="1" used

Tags: hive, hiveql

I create a table in hive based on a csv file from the following link
https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2017-11.csv

I used the below query,

```
create external table if not exists taxi_data(VendorID int,tpep_pickup_datetime string,tpep_dropoff_datetime string,
passenger_count int,trip_distance double,RatecodeID int,
store_and_fwd_flag string,PULocationID int,DOLocationID int,payment_type int,
fare_amount double,extra double,mta_tax double,
tip_amount int,tolls_amount int,improvement_surcharge double,
total_amount double)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
location '/common_folder/nyc_taxi_data/'
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

when the above query got executed successfully I used the below select statement to get the first 10 rows of the table

```
select * from taxi_data limit 10;
```

The returned table is as below

```
taxi_data.vendorid  taxi_data.tpep_pickup_datetime  taxi_data.tpep_dropoff_datetime taxi_data.passenger_count   taxi_data.trip_distance taxi_data.ratecodeid    taxi_data.store_and_fwd_flag    taxi_data.pulocationid  taxi_data.dolocationid  taxi_data.payment_type  taxi_data.fare_amount   taxi_data.extra taxi_data.mta_tax   taxi_data.tip_amount    taxi_data.tolls_amount  taxi_data.improvement_surcharge taxi_data.total_amount
taxi_data.vendorid  taxi_data.tpep_pickup_datetime  taxi_data.tpep_dropoff_datetime taxi_data.passenger_count   taxi_data.trip_distance taxi_data.ratecodeid    taxi_data.store_and_fwd_flag    taxi_data.pulocationid  taxi_data.dolocationid  taxi_data.payment_type  taxi_data.fare_amount   taxi_data.extra taxi_data.mta_tax   taxi_data.tip_amount    taxi_data.tolls_amount  taxi_data.improvement_surcharge taxi_data.total_amount

1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
2   1   2017-11-01 00:01:48 2017-11-01 00:03:47 1   0.4 1   N   
3   1   2017-11-01 00:18:22 2017-11-01 00:40:32 1   4.8 1   N   
4   1   2017-11-01 00:01:58 2017-11-01 00:15:57 1   3.7 1   N   
5   1   2017-11-01 00:18:53 2017-11-01 00:25:23 1   1.9 1   N   
6   1   2017-11-01 00:28:56 2017-11-01 00:38:22 1   2   1   N   
7   1   2017-11-01 00:40:35 2017-11-01 00:46:34 1   1.7 1   N   
8   1   2017-11-01 00:33:27 2017-11-01 00:33:34 1   0   1   N   
9   1   2017-11-01 00:34:16 2017-11-01 00:34:25 1   0   1   N   
10  1   2017-11-01 00:35:06 2017-11-01 00:35:21 1   0   1   N
```

My question is why is the first row returned as null even when I used `tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")` in the create table statement ?

Comment: Rows returned are not ordered and firs row returned may be not the first row in the file. try to `select * from taxi_data where vendorid is null` without and with "skip.header.line.count"="1". Also check your file does not contain extra newline characters `'\n'`

Comment: I see there are 2 null rows.

Comment: There are null records in the data file. And your query may return records not in the same order as in the file(s) because of parallel execution. skip.header is not related to your problem. it is null rows in the files, maybe extra newline character. It is not necessarily first row. It may be first but not guaranteed.